# Select particular row from a DataFrame based on value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count, pandas-groupby

I am doing sentiment Analysis project. I got the results. I counted the number of positive, neutral and negative.

Here's  the code

```
ltweet.groupby(['sentiment_type'])['sentiment_neutral'].count()


# ltweet= the name of object
# sentiment_type= column
#sentiment_neutral= column
```

Here;s the output

```
Out[105]:
sentiment_type
NEGATIVE     280
NEUTRAL     1308
POSITIVE    1193
Name: sentiment_neutral, dtype: int64
```

I only want to display the 'POSITIVE' only (not negative and neutral)

I tried other codes but still  get an error. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `s = ltweet.groupby(['sentiment_type'])['sentiment_neutral'].count()`, then `print (s['POSITIVE'])`

Comment: you want the positive records?

Comment: @MAttR , I want display that only  'POSITIVE    1193'

Answer (score 0):

Filter your dataframe first:

```
ltweet.query('sentiment_type == "POSITIVE"')\
      .groupby('sentiment_type')['sentiment_neutral'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`ltweet.groupby(['sentiment_type'])['sentiment_neutral'].count().loc['POSITIVE']`

From the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html

Comment: Yeah it shows me the value only (did not show positive).  I like to  see something like
POSITIVE  1193

Comment: `ltweet.groupby(['sentiment_type'])['sentiment_neutral'].count().loc[['POSITIVE']]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of doing it. Instead of using a group by, you can filter out only the positive sentiments and then count the number of rows

```
cnt_pos =ltweet[ltweet["sentiment_type"]=="POSITIVE"]["sentiment_type"].count()
```

For printing purposes

```
print("POSITIVE {0}".format(cnt_pos))
```